# Height of AVL Tree

Tags: search-trees, balanced-search-trees, binary-search-trees, avl-trees

I found an AVL tree implementation on the internet and experimented:
For a tree with node count of 2^20, the minimal and maximal tree heights are 16 and 24.
While these heights are lg(n)-ish, I am concerned about their difference.
Doesn't AVL guarantee maximal-minimal height difference to be 1?

The [repository](https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/williamfiset/algorithms/datastructures/balancedtree/AVLTreeRecursiveOptimized.java) from which I got the code

Comment: It should guarantee that, so it might be that what you have found is a more relaxed version of some sort of self balancing tree.

Comment: I dont think that its an AVL tree, cause theorietical bounds for min/max heights with n nodes  are logn and 1.44*logn which turns out to be the range 20-28 in this case. I agree that it might be a relaxed version of some self balancing tree. Maybe you could share the link to its implementation so that one can understand it better.

Comment: @RinkeshP: Provided a link to the repo. Thanks

Comment: No, AVL does _not_ require max-min height difference to be <=1 _on all paths_. It does require that, for each node, (max height of left subtree) and (max height of the right subtree) are at most 1 unit apart. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#/media/File:Fibonacci_Tree_6.svg

Comment: @Chi This very useful. If you could provide this as an answer(with the "max height" emphasized) I'll gladly mark it so.

Comment: Remember that the purpose of balancing a binary search tree is to avoid pathological behaviour. As long as you get $O(\log n)$ search times (i.e. within a reasonable constant factor) and not $O(n)$ search times, balancing has done its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AVL invariant does *not* guarantee that, given any two tree paths, their length differs at most by one unit. They can differ by more than one unit, as shown by the following tree (Fibonacci AVL tree from Wikipedia):

[image: Fibonacci Tree 6.svg]

Instead, the AVL invariant only requires that the heights of the two subtrees of any nodes differ at most by one. Note that the height of a (sub)tree is the *maximum length* of its paths. Therefore, the AVL invariant is equivalent to requiring that, for all nodes, the *maximum* length of a path in the left subtree and the *maximum* length of a path in the right subtree differ at most by one unit.

Note how we only take the paths giving the *maximum* length, and never the paths giving the *minimum* length.